# How can I fill my rich model from repository when I am no using ORM?

Tags: c#, .net-core, design-patterns

I am trying to develop my application using the DDD approach and I should set all of my properties private. I need to use Aerospike as my database and there is no ORM to fill my properties magically like EntityFramework with a private default constructor.
Now, How can I fill this reach model without exposing a full property constructor that can be accessible everywhere and can breach the rule of encapsulation business domain rules?

making all properties protected and creating an internal inherited class inside the repository namespace that can act as a proxy object to fill property can be a solution But I have no idea about the best practice and acceptable design.

Comment: "[...] and I should set all of my properties private" why? How is your application going to change any of your data? Let alone *read* any of your data if all your properties are private?. FYI if you're really determined to make all your properties private, you (or some other developer) could use reflection to still read/ write to the properties [like so](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jIYCvH)

Comment: I think You know nothing about DomainModeling and DDD; my Domain object has some functions that validate and check the command and will change the state of my model and these functions have many validation rules coming from the business side. when I am fetching the data from the database there is no need for that validation because I can be ensure all there validation are performed on command time.

Comment: Domain objects shouldn't know anything about business rules, they just hold data. Move your business rules away from the domain objects' getters and setters and to a separate service, then only call that service when required, i.e when mapping/ writing it to a database and don't when it's not needed

Comment: You are in the opposite direction that Domain-Driven Design is trying to guide the developers. anemic models are not a good practice in DDD and the state of the domain object should change by itself using methods that are based on UL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Aerospike, but here are my thoughts. First, EF is able to set private properties because it uses reflection to do so. And it needs a parameterless constructor for this. So you could do it the same way: create an object and set properties via reflection.

Or, as others pointed out in the comments, you will anyway need methods to set your private properties, so just use them to instantiate your model. You use private setters and methods in order to ensure that the state of your DDD object is valid and do some internal checks, e.g.:

```
public class Whatever {
   private int age;

   public int Age { get; private set; }

   public void UpdateAge(int a) {
      if (a > 0) {
         this.age = a;
      }

      throw new MyException();
   }
}
```

So just use `UpdateAge()` and the like. On the other hand it's not necessary to run extra validations if you are instantiating from a database, because all the data in the DB is valid. You could introduce some private variable, like `needsValidation`, and set it to false in case you are instantiating from the DB via e.g. an internal constructor. Whether it's really worth the effort depends on your use case.

Comment: your suggestion is good when my repositories are located in the same namespace as my domain models. whereas, the best practice says to separate the model namespace from other layers to add reusability to your domain Implementation without any thechnology consideration.

Comment: but your repositories should know about the domain objects, how would they otherwise return them? E.g. Task<Whatever> GetItem(long id) in WhateverRepository knows about Whatever class and its methods..

Comment: Yes it knows by It is inherited from IPersonRepository interface that is inside the Contract of Domain, and so my repository reference to my domain but cannot access the internal members